# Do i have to release the k pronunciation in the word "picture"?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, ipa

I was wondering about the pronunciation of the /k/ and /t/ in this word, `ˈpɪkʧər` - picture. Do I have to fully release the k?

Comment: What do you mean by "of the **k l** in this word"?

Comment: My best guess is that the asker typo'd, and either did not intend to include the "l" at all, or meant "/k/ and /t/" instead.  The latter actually seems a *lot* more likely to me, as it makes sense in the context of the question... I'm going to edit the question with this in mind, but please feel free to edit it again or comment here if I got your intended meaning wrong.

Comment: @RichardWinters What does fully release the k mean? Does it mean you have to say the k with full emphasis?

Comment: See my answer below for my best effort.  "Fully release" is not a standardized term, but again, from context, I think the meaning is clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When pronouncing this consonant cluster in AmE, use your tongue to stop the air in the manner of a /k/ but do not continue to the fricative portion of that sound.  (If this fricative portion of the sound is what you mean by "fully release", then the answer is "**no**", you do not fully release)

Instead, while the air is still stopped, move your tongue to the /t/ position in your mouth, and let the air go in the manner of /tʃ/.